# Two or more div width 100% of parent

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I have a parent div with variable width and height and overflow auto, then I have two or more children div with 100% with of parent.
I would like that all the children div have the same width, but when the parent has horizontal scroll, each children have different width.
See the example:

```css
#container {
  width: 175px;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
}

.block {
  height: 20px;
  background: aqua;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="block">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div class="block">bbb</div>
  <div class="block">ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</div>
  <div class="block">ssss</div>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS can't detect overflow...you'd need javascript.

Comment: The width of the inline-block element calculated according to is content

Comment: anytime you inject some sort of dynamism ( i dont know if that is a word) common CSS and HTML wont be able to handle it. Hence you need JS for this as you are trying to dynamically adjust the width property based on some circumstance

Comment: I used JS to set the width of each children, but when i change the parent div width the effect it's not good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```css
#container {
  width: 175px;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

.table {
  width:100%;
  display:table;
}

.block {
  height: 20px;
  background: aqua;
  display: table-row;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div class="table">
  <div class="block">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div class="block">bbb</div>
  <div class="block">ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</div>
  <div class="block">ssss</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Please note that I changed `display` to `table-row` which automatically removes the border, but in order to preserve it I added `border-collapse:collapse;` to `#container`.

**Edit**: Added a `div` with a class `"table"` + relevant CSS

Comment: That's good...but if the parent's width is greater than children's width, the children aren't 100% of parent as I'd like...try changing #container width to 375px; in the right side you will see the background color red

Comment: To achieve this you might need to add another `div` to contain blocks within `#container'. I will update the snippet now

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```css
    #container {
      width: 175px;
      background: red;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .block {
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 aqua;
      border: 1px solid yellow;
      float: left;
      height: 50px;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 175px;
      word-break: break-all;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="block">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  </div>
  <div class="block">bbb</div>
  <div class="block">ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</div>
  <div class="block">ssss</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to set display property here because if you set float property other than none, element will get its display property as block.

Comment: If i understood it right, then OP wants to have variable width to each of his child element only when horizontal scroll of parent is present. Or did I totally miss the question?

Comment: i dont understand for what he want build layout with overflow content outside div :)

Comment: I cannot answer that question. Maybe OP has a requirement where the parent's width is dynamic and is set by some other factor. Hence OP wants to set same width to child if no overflow is detected but have different width is overflow detected

Comment: The container is a draggable and resizeable div, its content can have different width. The children div has a table, so I cannot set the property word-break: break-all;